# Validation problem with checkbox when using Rules Validation Rule

Tags: rules-engine, validation

I've created an item rule using the `Rules Validation Rule` template.  The rule ensures that there is a value provided for EITHER a specific text field OR a specific checkbox field.

The rule works fine when toggling between a value and no value for the text field, but when toggling the checkbox field, it only reports a validation error after toggling to the unchecked stated and then saving TWICE.  Saving the first time after unchecking the box doesn't give an error.  I don't see this behavior with the text field. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the rule:
[image]
[image]

I've added the rule to the item template's standard values:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add more details on how is the rule implemented?

Comment: More details added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by inverting the logic for the checkbox field. Instead of using `is empty` I used `not equal to 1`

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I tried that earlier, and it didn't work, but perhaps doing that AND having the checkbox field come first did the trick.  Anyway, it's working now, so thanks.